# Add custom words and definitions to UIReferenceLibraryViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I would like to provide custom definitions for financial terms (in different languages) in my application using the `UIReferenceLibraryViewController`, which was introduced in iOS 5.

However, I have not found any  information on how to add custom definitions to the reference.

Do you have any suggestions on how to implement this useful feature?

Comment: From the documentation: _It should not be used to display wordlists, create a standalone dictionary app, or republish the content in any form._ So, you won't be able to add new definitions.

Comment: Hi Adig, do you have any idea on how to implement a custom dictionary using a different set-up?

Comment: A quick search on github gives some dictionary sample apps that could be a starting point. See : https://github.com/mattneary/Etymology-for-iPhone or https://github.com/ioseb/LinGEO

Comment: Adig, could you please put your comment as answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

`It should not be used to display wordlists, create a standalone dictionary app, or republish the content in any form`.

So, you won't be able to add new definitions.

A quick search on github gives some dictionary sample apps that could be a starting point. See : http://github.com/mattneary/Etymology-for-iPhone or http://github.com/ioseb/LinGEO